# Reading Chinese Characters in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, symfony

In a Symfony project, I have something like this:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($this->bigString());
$array = array();
foreach($crawler->filter('.editable') as $domElement )
{
    $innerHtml = $this->getChildHtml($domElement);
    $array[$domElement->getAttribute('id')] = $innerHtml;
    $domElement->nodeValue = '{{ listEditables["' . $domElement->getAttribute('id') . '"] }}';
    $crawler->addNode($domElement);
 }
$page->setEditables($array);
$em->persist($page);
$em->flush();
```

Where the bigString method returns

```
<div class="info pmt0 wrap">
  <p id="p_editable_2" class="editable">所谓设计，创于人，且用于人......</p>
  ... a bunch of other html element with Chinese in it ...
</div>
```

and I use

```
private function getChildHtml($node) 
{
    $innerHtml= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;

    foreach( $children as $child )
    {
        $innerHtml .= sprintf( '%s%s', $innerHtml, $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ) );
    }

    return $innerHtml;
}
```

to get the inner HTML.

I can't get the persisted elements to be accurately representing the Chinese characters, all I get is nonsense. Using

```
 var_dump($innerHtml);
```

shows that getChildHtml() doesn't return the original Chinese characters. Any idea how I can get it to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with Symfony Crawler.

As advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291435/symfony2-crawler-use-utf-8-with-xpath), a good workaround is to write

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addHtmlContent($this->bigString());
```

instead of

```
$crawler = new Crawler($this->bigString());
```

since the addHtmlContent method encode in UTF8 by default

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003505/php-sprintf-with-foreign-characters), `sprintf` won't help you. Instead, use something like [mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-substr.php).

```
$innerHtml .= mb_substr($child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ), 0);
```

Other than that, most probably the [right encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744473/using-utf-8-charset-with-php-are-mb-functions-required) will help you out.

Comment: mb_substr doesn't help. I'm aware it's encoding problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it

Comment: Well, make sure all files are utf8 encoded and set it manually in your php.

Comment: php.ini has utf-8 has a default charset, but it still changes nothing

Comment: Check saveXML() then. Seems like to be the next candidate.

Comment: Yep, that's the culprit.